# Using Assemble/Grunt, is it possible to lowercase & hyphenate a variable from YAML front matter

Tags: yaml

*I've already asked this question on [github](https://github.com/assemble/assemble/issues/178), but the developers asked me to put it here to see if anyone else had any other suggestions...*

Is it possible to dynamically convert a YAML front matter variable to lowercase and replace spaces with hyphens?

The reason I ask is that I'm adding a class to a div that contains a unique reference to the current page, in my case the page title. I already have the page title set in the front matter, so it would be great if I could simply reuse it.

To illustrate, it would be great if you could do something like this:

```html
---
title: My Page Title
---
<div class="{{ title.hyphenize }}">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    ...
</div>
```

That outputs this:

```html
<div class="my-page-title">
    <h1>My Page Title</h1>
    ...
</div>
```

I'm new to YAML Front Matter and what's possible with it, so any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm one of the developers on assemble, and I thought it would be better to have this on stackoverflow for reference. This is the answer I provided:

I think the best way to handle this is with either a handlebars helper or an underscore template. We provide a couple of handlebars helpers in the helper lib repo that can be used like the following...

```
---
title: My Page Title
---
<div class="{{hyphenate title}}">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    ...
</div>
```

This will replace spaces with hyphens, but it doesn't make it lowercase.

Another approach is to use a lodash template inside the yaml header:

```
---
title: My Page Title
class: <%= title.toLowerCase().split(" ").join("-") %>
---
<div class="{{class}}">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    ...
</div>
```

Also, @jonschlinkert added that you can combine the 2 approaches with something like this:

```
---
title: My Page Title
class: <%= title.toLowerCase() %>
---
<div class="{{hyphenate class}}">
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    ...
</div>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I didn't realise how powerful assemble/grunt was with the addition of handlebars helpers and lodash/underscore, so I was really pleased to be offered three possible solutions to my question. At the moment I'm using the second option as it keeps all the 'functionality' in the front matter and keeps the main body of the template and handlebars 'clean'.